# R when correlation is 1 an identical check with 1 gives FALSE

Tags: r, correlation

I have a weird problem with the following data frame (see below). Both columns are 100% identical, as can be seen by running `identical(x[,1], x[,2])`.

However, when I calculate the correlation between both columns (which mathematically is exactly 1), a check of this correlation against "1" gives FALSE and I've absolutely no idea why that is.

```
cor(x)[2,1]==1
cor(x[,1],x[,2])==1 # alternative
### Both give FALSE as results
```

However, when I use a randomly generated data set, I get the expected result, i.e. the correlation is identical to 1.

```
a=b=runif(50)
cor(a,b)==1
### Gives TRUE as result
```

I've no idea what's going on here. Any ideas?

Here's my data:

```
x=structure(list(ssc.check_loops = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2,
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Data.hNumber_of_loops = c(1, 1,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2,
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1,
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-586L))
```

Comment: Check out `sprintf("%.20f", cor(x[,1],x[,2]))`.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the answers. Very helpful. I sensed that it might have to do something with floating numbers, but then I was confused because all checks I did with randomly generated data (i.e. the runif(50) or runif(10000) checks) yielded the correct result: TRUE.